# How to append data to firebase in dialogflow fulfillment using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to add new data fields into existing list in firebase realtime database. I am using **push()** to generate unique ID in one of my function.
In the next function how do I map the new data under the same unique ID so that new data gets appended under the same ID.
Below is the fulfillment code:

```
function reportHandler(agent){
 const t2 = agent.parameters.name;
 const t3 = agent.parameters.college;
 const t4 = agent.parameters.branch;
 const t5 = agent.parameters.year;

 return admin.database().ref('data').push().set({
  name: t2,
  college: t3,
  branch: t4,
  year: t5
});
```

This code works perfectly and creates a unique ID field in the database. What I want to do next is to add new data into the previously created unique ID field.

```
function detailsHandler(agent){
 const t1 = agent.parameters.prtype;
 const t6 = agent.parameters.desc;
 const t7 = agent.parameters.when;

 return admin.database().ref('data').push().set({
  prtype: t1,
  desc: t6,
  when: t7
});
```

This is another function which has some values. I want values from both the functions into one field with unique ID.

**I am calling the functions with this**

```
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('Report', reportHandler);
intentMap.set('Report.details', detailsHandler);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

**New field with unique ID gets created but with values from only the first function** 
[image]

**This is what I want(values from both the functions into one field)** 
[image]

Comment: To be clear (since this is tagged dialogflow) - these two updates will be done in different Intent Handlers? So you don't get the values for "name" and "desc" from the same Intent, correct? (If this assumption isn't correct - showing the Intents in question, and exactly how you have the handlers registered, or how these functions are being called, will help us help you.)

Comment: Yes, they are two different intent handlers. And the values for "name" and "desc" are from different intents.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your question down into two parts:

- How do we update a record given its ID?
- How does the second Intent Handler know what ID to update?

**How do we update a record given its ID?**

You can't use the `push()` method, since this will save the data at a new ID. You also don't want to use the `set()` method, since this *replaces* data at the ID with new data.

Instead, you want to get a reference to the record with the ID, and then [update it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#update) with the `update()` method.

If we assume our ID is in a variable named, cleverly enough, `id`, this might look something like this

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('data').child(id);
return ref.update({
  prtype: t1,
  desc: t6,
  when: t7
});
```

But where do we get the ID from?

**How do we pass the ID from the first Intent Handler to the second?**

The ID is generated when we call `push()` in our first Intent Handler, so we need to capture it at that point.

But to get it to the second Intent Handler, we'll need to save it in a [context parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview) using the `agent.context.set()` method. The `set()` method takes the name of a context, an optional lifespan (how many Intent calls will this be saved for), and an object containing attribute/value strings.

This might look something like this:

```
const dataRef = admin.database().ref('data');
const newRef = dataRef.push();
const id = newRef.key;
return newRef.set({
  name: t2,
  college: t3,
  branch: t4,
  year: t5
})
.then( () => {
  agent.context.set({
    name: "reportInfo",
    lifespan: 5,
    parameters: {
      id: id
    }
  });
});
```

later, in your second Intent Handler, you'd get this ID out of the context using, you guessed it, `agent.context.get()`, and then getting the `id` parameter from it. So possibly something like this:

```
const reportInfoContext = agent.context.get('reportInfo');
const id = reportInfoContext.parameters.id;
```

and then use this as outlined above.